# controller not detected by steam

Tags: games, steam

I have a PS4 DualShock controller, and Ubuntu 20.04. I have Steam devices installed, but Steam says:

> No controllers detected.

It used to work and I don't know what made it stop working. I don't think I've updated recently. The computer can detect the controller, too, but Steam can't. I've tried both wired and wireless methods. I've tried different wires, none of which works. I have also tried this method: https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/1693795812304458372/

However, I tried a different controller and it works. So why can't I get mine working?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it work with other computers/consoles?

Answer (score 0):

Was scouring the internets yessterday after dealing with that exact problem and found this link hope it works for ya
https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/2930112548442481325

Comment: Please could you put the steps into your answer, not just a link? Then, if the link breaks, your answer is still useful. Thank you!